# In MVC 5, How do I remove the required attribute depending on another dropdown value?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Currently, the form is working as intended until you submit the form with the 
Usage_Status dropdown selection with value a of '2' and then switch to any other value and submit again.  The javascript validation message 'The Assigned User field is required.' appears and does not go away after switching values on the dropdown and submitting again.  Is it possible to remove the required attribute, or set it on the condition that '2' is selected?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Usage_Status, new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Usage_Status", new SelectList(statuses, "ID", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Usage_Status)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Assigned_User, new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Assigned_User, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Assigned_User)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Department, new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Department", new SelectList(departments, "ID", "Name"), string.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Department)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#Usage_Status').change(function (e) {
    //If item is being used, require a user and department. Otherwise, disabled those fields.
    if ($('#Usage_Status').val() == "2") {
        $('#Assigned_User').rules('add', 'required');
        $('#Assigned_User').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#Assigned_User').rules('remove', 'required');
        $('#Assigned_User').removeAttr('required');
        $('#Assigned_User').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }

});
```

Comment: Is it marked as required in your model?

Comment: Yes, it is marked in the model.

Comment: So when you submit it, the server side will bounce it too. client & server side validation are separate processes.

Comment: I just tried removing the attribute in the model, and it has the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing conditional validation, e.g one field's value in your form defines validation for another field you need an additional library. I use [expressive annotations](https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations)

Comment: I should probably make another question for this, but I'm hoping you can help me quickly.  Is this what I would put into the model? [RequiredIf("Usage_Status == '2'")]
        [Display(Name = "Assigned User")]
        public string Assigned_User { get; set; }

Comment: @sjohn285 Yep, just pass the conditions in as a string